# Images from my HTML Email is not opening in client's inbox

Tags: html, email, html-email, newsletter

I have an e-mailer created in HTML and having embedded images.
I need to send this to my clients in bulk.

But most of the email services like gmail, ymail & outlook are blocking the image and asking the user to download / Display images. **(Images are opening in hotmail)**
As this is a promotion email, no one is going to say download or display images then there is no use of my mailer.

Is there any process to crack this.

Comment: Could you provide some source code, and/or what system you are using to send this email?

Comment: I am sending simple HTML mail.. with simple `<img>` tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having images not download automatically is a security setting that is in place on most major email clients.  Saying that, there isn't something you can really trigger on your end from the sender's standpoint in order to bypass that.

You may consider encouraging in your emails to have them add your 'from' email address to their address books.  A lot of email clients will consider you a safe sender and in turn, download your images automatically for this particular recipient.

Otherwise, you may consider using base64 encoding to insert your images (this allows you to insert image content that doesn't need to be downloaded).  But it's up to you to see what email clients actually support the insertion of those types of images.  It's more than likely that you'll find the majority of email clients won't support it though.  If there was an easy way to bypass the security settings in order to force image downloads, wouldn't you think spammers would be abusing that by now?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link I always go back to when dealing with those issues. It lets you know which client does what and how to work around it as much as possible.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3574/